# zipObject in lodash v.4.x.x

Tags: node.js, lodash

According to the documentation of `lodash v3.10.1`, [it is possible](https://lodash.com/docs/3.10.1#zipObject) to use `_.zipObject` such like this:

```
_.zipObject([['fred', 30], ['barney', 40]]);
// => { 'fred': 30, 'barney': 40 }
```

but in lodash v.4.15.0 I,m gettin this:

```
_.zipObject([['fred', 30], ['barney', 40]]);
{ 'fred,30': undefined, 'barney,40': undefined }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a function I need in `lodash v4.15.0`. This function is [fromPairs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#fromPairs)